# How does a message is deleted by other party on my Facebook Marketplace messenger?

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-marketplace

I have had this happen a couple of times.  A buyer inquires to buy an item from me on the Facebook Marketplace.  After giving me the run around and after asking for my address I begin to find out that the entire message on the Marketplace messenger with the person on my end has vanished.
How is the other person able to do this.
To my knowledge when you delete a conversation, a chat or whatever, it says on the pop up menu that it gets deleted only on my end and that other party still has his or her own copy.

These are the closest option I see and none of them will delete a conversation for both side:

1. Ignore messages.
2. Delete chat.
3. Mute conversation.
4. Leave group.